Appium - Python. After scrolling to element and selecting it, country field remains unpopulated
I'm new to Appium and have been learning on my own. I used telegram and an actual Android device as a base for learning. However I hit a snag for the following sequence:

On the phone number input screen, I can click on country field which brings me to another screen with the list of countries

On this screen I am able to scroll down to find the country I want
to select

I am able to click on the country and return to the phone number
input screen

But on the phone number input screen, the country field remains
unpopulated, and appium returns with a StaleElementReferenceException error.

I googled and found
StaleElementReferenceException on Python Selenium
, so I implemented it but got a timeoutexception error, I increase
the webdriverwait timeout (from 10 to 20) but it didnt solve it. i
tried different selectors from appium inspector, uiautomator and
xpath but both didn't work.


So I suspect something is blocking the phone number input screen from refreshing with the selected country? or that somehow Appium is still on a old phone number input screen instance? I tried then to select a country (Albania) that doesn't require scrolling since its on top of the list, and I am able to see it populated in the country field. So somehow the scrolling is affecting it but I don't know why and how to fix it. some further googling mentions about "screen is refreshing while waiting for element to become visible" in my case, the screen doesnt refresh with the selected value even after explicit wait. Any ideas?
After scrolling, selecting a country, the value should be reflected in the country field and I'm able to assert that its the correct value.
    def test_select_country(self):
        #navigate to phone num input screen
        startMessenging_btn = wait_for_element(self.driver, AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text("Start Messaging")')
        assert startMessenging_btn is not None
        startMessenging_btn.click()
        
        #tap and navigate to country selection screen
        phone_num_screen_country_element = wait_for_element(self.driver, AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, 'Country')
        assert phone_num_screen_country_element is not None
        phone_num_screen_country_element.click()

        #scroll down to selected country
        scroll_to_country = self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 
                        'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(" Belgium").instance(0))'
                        )
        assert scroll_to_country.is_displayed()
        
        # somehow this only works when selecting a country without scrolling, it doesnt work after scrolling is completed, 
        # I can see the click on device but the next screen doesnt reflect the selected country
        select_country = self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR,'new UiSelector().text(" Belgium")') 
        assert select_country.text == " Belgium"
        select_country.click()

# this is where staleelementreferenceexception was found, does appium reloads this screen when it comes back to it?
        phone_num_screen_country_populated = wait_for_element(self.driver, AppiumBy.XPATH, '//android.widget.TextView[@text=" Belgium"]')
        assert phone_num_screen_country_populated.text == " Belgium"

def wait_for_element(driver: 'WebDriver', locator: str, value: str, timeout_sec: float = 10) -> 'WebElement':
"""Wait until the element located

Args:
    driver: WebDriver instance
    locator: Locator like WebDriver, Mobile JSON Wire Protocol
        (e.g. `appium.webdriver.common.appiumby.AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID`)
    value: Query value to locator
    timeout_sec: Maximum time to wait the element. If time is over, `TimeoutException` is thrown

Raises:
    `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

Returns:
    The found WebElement
"""
ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)
return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_sec, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).\
until(EC.presence_of_element_located((locator, value)))

Phone number input screen
Country Selection screen

so after much trial and error, I think I stumbled upon a solution which so far is working:
at the end of the commands for each page, i added time.sleep(), i tried with 1 or 2 seconds but it didn't work, so i just increased it to 10 and it worked!
What I don't understand is that the customized webdriverwait function wait_for_element is supposed to replace time.sleep, in that it detects the elements are loaded before interacting with them.
Is there a more efficient way to detect the whole page is functional before I interact with it and move to the next page?

If that worked for you, you can add an Answer to your own Question.

so after much trial and error, I think I stumbled upon a solution which so far is working: at the end of the commands for each page, i added time.sleep(), i tried with 1 or 2 seconds but it didn't work, so i just increased it to 10 and it worked! fine tuned it and reduced it to 5 seconds
